# How to get full text inside lxml element

Tags: python, lxml

I have the following html:

```
<span class="episode">Episode: <a href="/title/tt2071912/">
    !Que ve el Bisbe!</a>
    (2011)
</span>
```

How would I get the year from this? When I get the episode object, it only gives me the 'text' before the `<a>`:

```
result.cssselect('.episode')[0].text
'Episode: '
```

The best I have so far is:

```
year = lxml.html.tostring(result.cssselect('.episode')[0]).split('(')[-1].split(')')[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.text` property](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#elements-contain-text) of the enclosing element.